# Keyboard tab does not set focus to mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material, accessibility

I need some help with accessibility issues on my Angular 14 application. I am using angular material dropdown element and when I use the keyboard tab key to
check accessibility, the dropdown element is not getting focused. I have tried the tabindex = 0 and also tried using the :focus inside my css but the dropdown does not get the focus. Here is my HTML:

```
<div [formGroup]="selectFormGroup">
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
   <i aria-hidden="true" class="select-icon material-icons">
  {{ myDropdown.panelOpen ? 'expand_less' : 'expand_more' }}
</i>
<mat-select #myDropdown placeholder="Consumer Goods" disableOptionCentering panelClass="my-select" (selectionChange)="onChangeSelected($event)"
formControlName="select" [disableRipple]="true" aria-label="'Please select from given options'" tabindex="0">
  <div class="select-underline"></div>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
    {{option.name}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```